# IE8 can't download pdf file

Tags: model-view-controller, pdf, internet-explorer-8, header

I have MVC application that return PDF file.

```
 public FileStreamResult GetDocument(int id)
 {
   return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", documentsModel.Name);
 }
```

I have two test server. One is private and another is public.

From private I can download document and I get:

```
GET /Documents/GetDocument/3576 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-GB
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: appserver
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=vgzn4qkelxdmic3nbaqftsxd; .FidesAuthCookie=BF08E0DCAAA54D7D78AB6BD30D5ECA523C045F9B401B10693B6CE57D7D4C677C0908E24D92511DC75A487D6CAE6DD780AA8B4419A5A5D9258A4985AF6870D3AD1A0B3C01B8A620A1E14FEDDE298CCE255AE4B4C2F76D2635B8C5DF332AF19AAB; dynatree-active=3576; dynatree-focus=; dynatree-expand=496%2C603%2Cfolder_622; dynatree-select=


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
**Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0**
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: .FidesAuthCookie=BF08E0DCAAA54D7D78AB6BD30D5ECA523C045F9B401B10693B6CE57D7D4C677C0908E24D92511DC75A487D6CAE6DD780AA8B4419A5A5D9258A4985AF6870D3AD1A0B3C01B8A620A1E14FEDDE298CCE255AE4B4C2F76D2635B8C5DF332AF19AAB; expires=Fri, 13-Apr-2012 13:31:05 GMT; path=/
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2012 13:01:04 GMT
Content-Length: 49613
```

From my public server I get

```
GET /Documents/GetDocument/97 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-GB
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: beta.qi-care.nl
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=h3utp0bfu4zwhqysntame3we; dynatree-active=97; dynatree-focus=; dynatree-expand=4%2Cfolder_10; dynatree-select=; .FidesAuthCookie=F0DED3D98BF4115C910B0A29EC2C809902B49F15518952DFA78DDB4358B5F0C1A9EDAFB50DD0CA761B433ED68034C2539ABCCDA0C50FF5EEEE3573D3C77E550416CDB24B302C9EB831AC597040E6D255E9B582E8A29D5FC03454F2A0742ECC9DEC61070091F9A66D1C3FC7F9CA10C1B8BB9B5109CB613C98AEE32AFE5A0F8A28



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
**Cache-Control: private, no-cache="Set-Cookie", s-maxage=0**
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: .FidesAuthCookie=F0DED3D98BF4115C910B0A29EC2C809902B49F15518952DFA78DDB4358B5F0C1A9EDAFB50DD0CA761B433ED68034C2539ABCCDA0C50FF5EEEE3573D3C77E550416CDB24B302C9EB831AC597040E6D255E9B582E8A29D5FC03454F2A0742ECC9DEC61070091F9A66D1C3FC7F9CA10C1B8BB9B5109CB613C98AEE32AFE5A0F8A28; expires=Fri, 13-Apr-2012 13:19:35 GMT; path=/
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2012 12:49:35 GMT
Content-Length: 49613
```

and I get error

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308

For some reason, I have from these two server, two different responses. But I found on Microsoft support that client should change registry

```
To resolve this issue in Internet Explorer 7 and in Internet Explorer 8, follow these steps:
Start Registry Editor.
 For a per-user setting, locate the following registry key:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
 For a per-computer setting, locate the following registry key:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
 On the Edit menu, click Add Value.
 To override the directive for HTTPS connections, add the following registry value:
    "BypassSSLNoCacheCheck"=Dword:00000001
 To override the directive for HTTP connections, add the following registry value:
    "BypassHTTPNoCacheCheck"=Dword:00000001
 Quit Registry Editor.
```

[Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308)

Answer (score 0):

We faced this problem at work, it turned out to be a bug in Internet Explorer (in our case IE8-), that gives an error when trying to download a file in SSL (Are you in https, right?). The problem is that if the server sends to the browser an http header that disables caching, Explorer gives an error. In your case, `maxage=0` is equivalent to `Cache-Control: no cache`.

The solution server side is that you should overwrite this header to tell IE8 to cache the response, with `Cache-Control: private` for example.
Be careful that some application servers (such as in our case Websphere Application Server) append automatically `no-cache="Set-Cookie"` when a cookie is set.

Finally, there is another solution, if applicable, that solves the problem, but it should be applied client-side on the browser:

look at Method 1:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549423